# matching many patterns in single strings

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to find the strings that matches all patterns.

#### Code:

```
import re
mail_li = ['lokesh.g@uni-passau.de',
'lokesh dot gat uni-passau dot de',
'lokesg.g(at)uni-passau.de',
'lokesh.g(at) uni-passau.de',
'onefullword@gw.uni-passau.de',
'lokesh(dot) g(at) uni-passau (dot) de',
       '@laskdjak']


regex = r"(de$)(@)"


for i in mail_li:

    if(re.findall(regex,i)):
       print(i)
```

I want to check all the conditions like:

1. @ symbol or at or (at)
2. dot or .de
3. de at end

I tried to write regex but its not working properly.
Can someone help?

Comment: If in fact you are trying to parse email-addresses, please say so. There are libraries that will pull out all the parts and still be correct for weird addresses.

Comment: it's not about e-mail addresses. i want to search two patterns in string. ex: both @ and de

Comment: If you want to check if there is `@` or `de` at the end, use `re.search(r'@|de$', s)`. If you want to check for a sequence of them, try `re.search(r'@.*de$', s)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex will match:

1. `@` or `(at)`
2. `dot` or `.`
3. `de` at end
4. text without spaces

[`^(?=.*?\b(?:@|\(at\))\b)(?=.*?\b(?:\.|dot)\b).*(?<=de)$`](https://regex101.com/r/jyYuqQ/2)

However this regex will also match `email@un.passde` which is not desired. So if we modify the requirements to:

1. `@` or `(at)`
2. `(dot)de` or `.de` at end
3. text without spaces

we get the regex:

[`^(?=.*?\b(?:@|\(at\))\b).*(?=\b(?:\.|\(dot\))de$).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/jyYuqQ/2)